# buttons not keeping up with slider when window re-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever i re-size my window the slider buttons (next/previous) disappear and do not move with the slider. Any idea on how to fix this?
JSFIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/b31kvqwr/

Buttons CSS:

```
#nav img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:grey;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;



}
#prev {
    margin-left: 530px;
    font-size: 10px;

}
#next {
    right: -30px;
    margin-top: 13px;

}
```

PS: if the result in the jsfiddle doesn't show, expand the result tab.

This is how the slider looks like when full screen (the right way);
[image]

This what happens when i re-size the browser horizontally:

[image]

The buttons aren't moving with the slider. Any help please?

Comment: @Tiny Giant as you requested

Comment: Just to let you know, deleting questions can get you question banned. In the future, please [edit] your existing question, but thanks for including the requested images.

Comment: I honestly can't figure out how this code is supposed to function. Try removing all unnecessary styling and slim it down to the [shortest amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue](http://sscce.org/) Then @ping me and I'll take another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem at the moment is that you are using `margin-left:530px;` meaning that the arrows will always be 530px from the left of the screen no matter the size of the screen. It also looks like what ever is wrapping it has a set width and isn't resizing, your code was to messy for me to find this but there are a few thing that I found to make the problem a little better,

https://jsfiddle.net/b31kvqwr/2/

I have managed to keep it the correct place for a lot of the, however to improve get it working perfectly you will need to create 1-2 `@media`queries to tweet the alignments at different sizes to make it perfect.

The way I did this was by changing `margin-left` to `position:absolute` and use a `left` positioning instead on your prev and next buttons;

```
#prev {
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    position:absolute;  
}
#next {
    margin-top: 13px;
    left:58%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

As I side note I would recommend cleaning up your code like @TingGaint said as it is insanely messy. Also when posting on stack try only include the relevant code not all of it as it makes it quicker and easier to look through and help.

**EDIT**

I have found the problem, still do what I said above however now instead of have the arrows div where they are now, move them out and so there below <`div id="wrapper">` however you will have to play around with the placement as they will be at the top of the screen. However now they stay in the same place when re-sizing!

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/b31kvqwr/4/